# Appending text after using [innerHtml]

Tags: angular

Using Angular I have created a table with repeatable dropdown options. I have created the following global variable for the options:

```
this.dropdown = `
  <option [ngValue]="1">1</option>
  <option [ngValue]="2">2</option>
  <option [ngValue]="3">3</option>
  <option [ngValue]="4">4</option>
`
```

I am using this in my HTML with a safe HTML pipe with:

```
<td>
  <select [innerHtml]="dropdown | safeHTML"></select>
  Alert
</td>
```

I would like to simplify this further by using:

```
this.dropdown = `
  <select>
    <option [ngValue]="1">1</option>
    <option [ngValue]="2">2</option>
    <option [ngValue]="3">3</option>
    <option [ngValue]="4">4</option>
  </select>
`
```

along with

```
<td [innerHtml]="dropdown | safeHTML">
  Alert
</td>
```

Using this method results in the text "Alert" to be missing.

How can I solve this?

I have created a [StackBlitz for this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scdcrs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the following syntax, you are setting the cell content in two different ways at the same time. Apparently, the value bound to `innerHTML` overrides the literal content of the element.

```
<td [innerHtml]="dropdown | safeHTML">
  Alert
</td>
```

You can have the text appended to the value of `dropdown` with this syntax:

```
<td [innerHtml]="dropdown + 'Alert' | safeHTML">
</td>
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8mder2) for a demo.